# Login to Bitbucket Cloud API with Google Account

Tags: c#, bitbucket, google-signin

Is it possible to login to Bitbucket cloud API (1.0 or 2.0) with Google Account? It is possible through a webpage but I can't find information how to do it for REST API. I know how to get access_token from Google but how can I use google token to login to Bitbucket? I'm developing in C# but that doesn't really matter. Basically I'm trying to implement this functionality in my app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use **App password** for that. See [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html).